# Scala: passing function parameters as tuple

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say I have:

```
def foo(i: Int, s: String)
```

and have:

```
val tuple: (Int, String) = (1, "s")
```

can I pass `tuple` to `foo` without adding a wrapper for `foo`?

Comment: Yes you can do this with lambda notation. check answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible. Using `.tupled` one can convert the lambda into accepting the tuple as argument.

## Scala REPL

```
scala> def foo(i: Int, s: String): Int = i
foo: (i: Int, s: String)Int

scala> (foo _).tupled
res3: ((Int, String)) => Int = scala.Function2$$Lambda$226/234698513@45984654

scala> val tuple: (Int, String) = (1, "s")
tuple: (Int, String) = (1,s)

scala> (foo _).tupled(tuple)
res5: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo(tuple._1, tuple._2)` should work.

If you want something more maintainable, I would recommend following:

```
type MyTuple = (Int, String) 

def foo(t:MyTuple) = ??? // some code 

val tuple = (1, "s")

foo(tuple) // works
```

Also inside `foo`, the best way to unwrap the tuple would be

```
val (int, string) = t
```

Comment: :) no I want something more maintainable.

Comment: Edited answer for a better way, which I used most of the time.